# how to convert multiple images to cbr?

Tags: convert

this might be a newbies question, i have a lot of image files with different extension (`*.jpg`, `*.png`) and i want to convert it to `cbr` file format.

Is there a way to achieve this or are there command to do this ? (preferably using terminal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after reading the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_archive) , it turns out that cbr is rar file format. so, the solution is very simple :

```
sudo apt-get install rar       # install rar
rar a <comic_name>.cbr *.jpg   # compress it and add to cbr
```

very simple. hopefully, this will be helpful to someone.
thx to anyone who has read this article.